# En Dash in file path batch job query

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Hoping someone can help.
I have a batch job (Windows env) which simply copies a file to another folder.

```
copy "\\ACP-MS-NAS21\Global\MEC Daily Productivity\Business Analysts\Master_List\HCP_Master_List.xlsx" ^
     "\\ACP-MS-NAS21\Global\CSD [?] DWP Medical Services\CSL_CSD_DB\Master_List"
```

But I get the following error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I can see there's an en dash in the file path which I believe is causing the problem.
Is there any way to have a wildcard in the file path or any other way the job can recognise this?

Thanks in advance.
PS. newbie at batch programming, coding etc, so please can explanations be in plain English.  Many thanks

Comment: I don't see an Emdash did you replace it with `[?]` ? What code page do you use (`chcp`) An alternative might be to execute that command in powershell with default UTF16 encoding

Comment: Why don't you fix the folder name?

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry I pasted the code I was trying to use (rather than the original), my bad.  Thought about changing the folder name, but there are a lot of users who will probably have shortcuts, etc set up to stuff in there, will probably cause more headaches than just fixing the script :)

Comment: Windows tracks stuff like this. It will fix the shortcuts. There is a service running that monitors this. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/distributed-link-tracking-and-object-identifiers and the precise thing Windows will do when they use the shortcut is detailed here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishelllinka-resolve

Answer (score 0):

The command-line windows (and by extension - BAT files) operate in `OEM` codepage by default. Which exact codepage is defined by your OS settings (`Language for non-Unicode programs` or similar). Therefore you cannot normally use anything outside ASCII or whatever codepage you have.

### Save script as UTF-8

To use those characters you will need to work in a codepage that actually has them. `UTF-8` is the best one for this tasks (and probably the only one that will work in your case).

First, save your script as UTF-8. In `notepad` you can select codepage from `save as` menu.

If your editor does not allow you to select `UTF-8 (no BOM)` leave first line of your BAT file blank as some editors may preface your file a special header called `BOM` that helps detecting codepage. If it does and you leave 1st line blank you will get a `Bad command or file name` error as soon as your script starts but this won't prevent it from running properly.

### Select UTF-8 codepage

Now, your script is in `UTF-8` but windows command processor will still execute it as if it was in `ASCII`, thus corrupting all special characters. To specify our encoding we need to add following command, preferentially as a first non-blank line of your script, including comments (those may have non-ASCII characters in them - with unpredictable results)

```
CHCP 65001
```

`CHCP` changes current codepage to `65001` which is internal codepage number for `UTF-8`.

This works because latin letters and numbers in `UTF-8` have the same encoding as in `ASCII` and `OEM` codepages. Thus your scripts starts executing in `OEM` codepage, but since `CHCP 65001` command itself does not have non-ASCII characters it understood correctly. All following commands will be executed in UTF-8 and may have non-ASCII characters.

You may now insert `em-dash` into the filename and it won't be replaced with `?` upon saving.

### Set UTF-8 font

Unfortunately default console window font does not display UTF-8 correctly so you won't be able to see non-ASCII characters correctly. 
To solve this you should right-click command-line window title bar, select `properties`, and change font to UNICODE one. `Consolas`, `Lucida Console` and `Courier New` should work.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Am new to all this scripting, etc (learning a lot as I go) so will try some of this out.  There are other elements to my script (copying some other files to various locations) - am assuming implementing the above won't affect this? (there are no other odd characters in my script)

Comment: As long as you follow my recommendations (i.e. save the whole batch file in UTF-8) it should not affect anything else regardless of characters.  Please try it out and tell if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.
I've had to make a design change to my DB so have managed to get around the need to do this now (phew :))

Thanks again