# Replace last _ when renaming files

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete all 「name.jpg」 and rename 「name_.jpg」 to 「name.jpg」 in windows.
The file structure is like this.

```
>upperFolder
  >p1
    >學生_二反田●雄.jpg
    >學生_二反田●雄_.jpg
    >學生_半田●男.jpg
    >學生_半田●男_.jpg
    >學生_潘●.jpg
    >學生_潘●_.jpg
    >...
  >...
  >p7
    >學生_石井節●.jpg
    >學生_石井節●_.jpg
    >學生_王裕●.jpg
    >學生_王裕●_.jpg
    >學生_●垣  勇.jpg
    >學生_●垣  勇_.jpg
```

> delete p1/學生_二反田●雄.jpg
>
> rename p1/學生_二反田●雄_.jpg p1_學生-二反田●雄.jpg

The final result looks as below.
p1_ is to prevent repeat filename and - seperate student name.

```
>upperFolder
  >p1_學生-二反田●雄.jpg
  >p1_學生-半田●男.jpg
  >p1_學生-潘●.jpg
  >...
  >p7_學生-石井節●.jpg
  >p7_學生-王裕●.jpg
  >p7_學生-●垣  勇.jpg
```

How can I make this in bat or php?

I have tried

```
mkdir tmp

for /f "eol=: delims=" %%D in ('dir /b /s /ad *^|sort /r') do (
  pushd "%%D"
  for %%F in (*) do move "%%F" "..\%%~nxD_%%F" >nul
  popd
)

move *_.jpg tmp
del *.jpg
cd tmp 
move *.jpg .. 2>NUL
```

but can't get rid of the last '_'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no wildcards in CMD to not match a character, so instead you could temporally change the extension of the files whose names end with _:

**Note**: remember to run the following snippets from upperFolder and to change the %g for %%g if you're running from a batch file.

```
:: /r stands for recursive and ~n stands for (file)name
for /r %g in (*_.jpg) do ren %g "%~ng.jphg"
```

Then you can delete the files whose names do not end with _:

```
del /s *.jpg
```

And finally rename and move the files whose names end with _. But you're asking for something tricky and that is to prepend the filename with the directory name containing it, replace the inner _ of the filename with -, remove the trailing _ of the filename, and then move the file to upperFolder:

```
:: so that the variable expansion inside for's works as expected
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:: loop through all the directories and store the names in g
for /d %g in (*) do (
    for %h in ("%g\*_.jphg") do (
        set "newname=%~nh"
        :: remove trailing _
        set "newname=!newname:~0,-1!"
        :: replace ALL _ with -, assuming the filename only has one inner _
        set "newname=!newname:_=-!"
        :: prepend directory name and restore extension
        set "newname=%g_!newname!.jpg"
        :: rename and move to current directory
        move %h ".\!newname!"
    )
)
```

Comment: The source's file path contained space. I added double quote to source into first command: ren "%g" "%~ng.jphg" as well as last command move "%h" ".\!newname!" .These scripts worked fine. I am grateful for your first register help. Appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for you:

```
for %%a in (*.jpg) do del /y "%%~a" & ren "%%~na_%%~nx" "%%~nxa"
```

Here we:

- search all files of type `jpg`

  - delete those found
  - and then rename files with same name ending with `_` into names of original files

See `for /?` command or [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) for more information about `%%~na` and similar.

Please note that unless your system `OEM` codepage supports kanji this will not work. You can get around this problem by switching to `UTF-8` encoding by issuing command `CHCP 65001` and saving batch file as `UTF-8 (no BOM)`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392237/en-dash-in-file-path-batch-job-query/53401939#53401939) for more information.